# How can I import a library to a Java project in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I needed a class that could create polygons with Double or Float numbers, instead of int numbers. Well, I found it [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/ext/awt/geom/Polygon2D.html), and [here is the Jar file download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/ABC/Downloadbatikawtutil17jar.htm). I extracted the Jar and added it to the libraries in NetBeans; but now, I don't know how to import the package to my project. If I type "import org.apache.batik.ext.awt.geom;", it says that the package does not exist. How can I import that package to my project? Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

It's very easy.. you just expand the project tree in netbeans and right click to Libraries folder which is in the project.. and select the Add Jar/Folder option and choose your downloaded jar file.. nad click to open.. after that you can able to import these libraries..

[image: prreview]

Comment: Thank you very much. I just started using NetBeans today, so I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to define the library in Netbeans. You need to add the library to your project. Then your import will work.

After defining the library in Netbeans (under *Tools - Libraries*) you can add it as follows to the project: Right-click *Libraries* in your project tree, select *Add Library...* and then select your newly defined library.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I do that? I have tried to do it in Netbeans and it doesn't work

Comment: So the answer is a secret