# How can I add java client library in java on netbeans?

Tags: java, api, netbeans

Hello i read that I have to use the java client library in java to get the revisions list in google drive using google api. I use netbeans. I search for this question and I try to add the bib but i haven't get success. To download the library i visited this [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Downloads)  and downloaded the "latest". but after add the jar files I get the message error that the package doesnt exist. Please someone help me!

Yes! I try this but it show the same erros. I add the lib but netbeans (8) show the error in the three lines code: "package [name] doesn't exist".
The three lines are these:

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Revision;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.RevisionList;
```

***obs: the full code, taken in the google developers site is:***

```
package javaapplication8;    

import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Revision;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.RevisionList;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class MyClass {

  private static List<Revision> retrieveRevisions(Drive service,
    String fileId) {

      fileId = "1XpNdeTFBr2KygyfPtlowBvkpcaJJzjgLckrGjp5oOhg0";
  try {
    RevisionList revisions = service.revisions().list(fileId).execute();
    return revisions.getItems();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
  }
  return null;
  }


}
```

Comment: For adding the jar did you this: "Right click 'libraries' in the project list, then click add"?

Comment: Simple instruction whith images.



   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318598/how-can-i-import-a-library-to-a-java-project-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the error like package is missing, please check whether you have created a folder named com in your project or not. Also, every dot (.) indicates the levels of packages that you use in your project. Please check that com folder followed by the other folder names after every dot are present or not. I think this might help you. I answered your question based on my understanding (i.e, package issue which will be resolved by creating folders in your project. folders means packages). I am sorry if I gave you the wrong answer.