# How to import library into netbeans that I downloaded from github?

Tags: java, github, netbeans

I just download a java library from Github but I don't know how to import it into netbeans, please take a look at the link behind and guide me, thanks:
https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook 
OK, more detail about my question, I can't import to use that library after Add all what I download from Github!  I guess It's not added already!

Comment: Oh, come on! my question is a bad one but use can help me! right? Guiding me and I will accept your question. Why I have to take negative access?

Comment: This [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318598/how-can-i-import-a-library-to-a-java-project-in-netbeans) may help you

Comment: your question is not answerable. Is it a plain Netbeans project? Or do you use Maven or Gradle to manage libraries? Because there is more than one way and you don't specify which one you use, it is nearly impossible to help.

Comment: Convert that library to a jar file, then you could use it if it is put under jar resources in netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Download section in your link 
Kindly you can download zip folder from [here](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/releases/download/2.1.0/jnativehook-2.1.0.zip) then get jar file from bin folder

or
you can user Maven

```
<groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
<artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
```